# Issue on sprintf in Matlab

Tags: matlab, printf, number-formatting, scientific-notation

How to print in Matlab Like following....

```
0.01000E+02
```

I have tried

```
sprintf('%12.5e',[0.01000E+02])
```

it is giving me

```
1.00000e+000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You format is a bit specific. You should consider writing your own output function.

But a few pointers:

- Make e large with `upper`
- only 2 digits in exp number through a regexp. `new_string = regexprep(old_string,'\d(\d{2})$','\1')`
- the thing with leading 0 in exp representation is not standard - so maybe multiply with `1e2`, print the float and later attach the `E+02`.

Comment: Thanks....However,,This '0.01000E+02' would be any exp number...such as 0.01000E-10....

Comment: Just to clarify you  want the result in the pattern 0.02345E+67? Meaning always 2 zeroes in front no matter what the number is?

Comment: Sorry for making it hard to undersand...Yes, pattern is 0.XXXXXXXXE+XX...(Xis any number between (0-9)..Many thanks

Comment: ok then the question is how do you decide if it is `0.10000E01` or `0.01000E02` or `0.00001E05`

Comment: @user974194: that's the whole point of using **normalized** [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), the first digit will always be between 1 and 9, which gives us a unique representation. Otherwise, how do you choose from the many possible forms (as bdecaf shows in the comment above)

Comment: Thanks all....:)....@bdecaf: Another matlab code generates exponential numbers like 1.0000E-001/1.0000E+002.....My code need to reshape it to 0.10000E01 format.....Which is then used by another code developed by someone I do not know....So...:(..Thanks again for your time...:)

Comment: Would be very interesting to know in which field you work in that notation. Can you share?

Answer (score 1):

Something like `['0.0' strrep(sprintf('%12.5E',v*100), '.', '')]` (with `v` your value) should work if I understand correctly your format.